# Can't share a file, which contains "Unknown group" as a collaborator

Tags: java, google-drive-api

In GDrive I have a file, which is shared with two workmates and a group. The group is a little strange because it names is - "Unknown group". Please, see below P.S. which shows how it looks like.

[image]

Now, I want to share this file, using [Permissions: insert method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert), with other workmate. And I have a problem because I always receive an exception. Please, see below P.S, which shows Google APIs request and response:
[image]

Could you tell me, why I have "Unknown group" in my collaborators list? I don't remember whether I added some group before. Maybe I have added one group and somebody removed it from domain, using Google Admin panel, and now I have it as "Unknown group". Is it possible?

Why I am not able to add any other permission? I have 5 files which have "similar" group. For all of it I receive same exception. For other files, which don't contain "ghost" group share method works properly.

**EDIT**
I have checked [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) method and it doesn't work also. I receive same "500 Internal server error" message.

Comment: There is a known bug on Drive that leads to this situation. I don't know when we can provide a fix.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Do you create any issue on public issue service? (could you provide a link to it?) As I understand, now all files which contain "Unknown group" won't be shared with any other people. Maybe some workaround exists for this problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Could you file an issue on Google Drive's product mailing list?

Comment: OK, I have added it just a minute ago - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/drive/IChw49DSqHQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a few days on testing this functionality and I noticed that everything works OK. Despite the fact that exception is occured - the permission is granted to the corresponding file. I confirm it using [Documents List API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/).

```
try {
    driveApi.grantPermission(userEmail, fileId, permission);
} catch(GoogleJsonResponseException cause) {
    if (documentsListApi.listPermissions(userEmail, fileId).contains(permission)) {
        //OK
    } else {
        throw cause;
    }
}
```

For me it works perfectly. Please, let me know when you fix this bug. I will remove this additional confirmation.